# Fastest algorithm for finding an expression of a number as a sum of 4 or less primes

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms

We know from the proof of the ternary Goldbach problem, that every positive integer $\ge 2$ can be expressed as a sum of $4$ or lesser number of primes.

Can anyone share some fast algorithms that are known for writing a number as a sum of $4$ or less primes ?

Anyone knowing any algorithm which works faster than the naive algorithm for computing sums of primes, is welcome to share the details, or reference.

Comment: How many primes? You can write it as a bunch of $2$s, and a $3$ if the number is odd.

Comment: I meant $ \le 4$ many primes. I have fixed the question. Thanks !